# Compiler error when casting Dictionary to AnyObject?

Tags: ios, swift, casting, nsjsonserialization

I'm trying to make a simple extension in Swift that will make it easy to convert a Dictionary to JSON NSData using `NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject`.

```
extension Dictionary {
    func toJSONData() -> NSData! {
        return NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject(self, options: nil, error: nil)
    }
}
```

I can't quite figure out why this will not compile. It gives me a type error:

`Cannot downcast from 'Dictionary<Key, Value>' to non-@objc protocol type 'AnyObject'`

Any Ideas? I've googled around and couldn't find anything.

### note:

I've tested this and it works just fine:

```
return NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject(["":""], options: nil, error: nil)
```

Comment: The problem is that not all Swift dictionaries can be converted to `AnyObject`, only those the type `[NSObject: AnyObject]`. And defining an extension of a generic type that applies only to certain restricted generic types seems not to be possible (there were similar Q&A for array extensions).

Comment: @MartinR Yep, after playing around a bit more, I realized I was extending `Dictionary` and no `NSDictionary`. Throw that into an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*(From my above comment:)* The problem is that not all Swift dictionaries can be converted to `AnyObject`, only those the type `[NSObject: AnyObject]`. And defining an extension of a generic type that applies only to certain restricted generic types seems not to be possible (there were similar Q&A for array extensions).

You can use a function (as Nate suggested in his answer), or define an extension
for `NSDictionary` instead.

---

Update for **Swift 2:** As of Swift 2, you *can* define an extension of a generic type that applies only to certain restricted generic types:

```
extension Dictionary where Key : NSObject, Value : AnyObject {
    func toJSONData() -> NSData! {
        return try? NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject(self, options: [])
    }
}
```

Then

```
let d1 = ["foo" : "bar"].toJSONData()
```

compiles and works as expected, but

```
struct Bar {} 
let d2 = [ "foo" : Bar() ].toJSONData()
```

does not compile because `Bar()` is not an `AnyObject`.

Answer (score 1):

The compiler is complaining because a `Dictionary` (in its generic form) can theoretically hold non-bridgeable types, like a Swift enum. You can define a top-level function and put constraints on both the key and the value types for the dictionary this way:

```
func toJSONData<T1: _ObjectiveCBridgeable, T2: _ObjectiveCBridgeable>(dict: [T1: T2]) -> NSData! {
    return NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject(dict, options: nil, error: nil)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Did you consider extending NSData instead?
The resulting code is pretty neat:

```
extension NSData {
    convenience init(jsonDictionary: [String:AnyObject]) throws {
        self.init(data:
            try NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject (
                jsonDictionary,
                options: NSJSONWritingOptions(rawValue: 0)
            ))
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
let jsonData = try NSData(jsonDictionary: ["foo": 313, "fee": "bar"])
```

Answer (score -1):

```
func simplePostMethod()  
{

let url : URL = URL(string: "writ your URL here")!

var request = URLRequest(url: url)

let session = URLSession.shared

request.httpMethod = "POST"


// Below are input parameter, you can put your input parameter.

 let params = ["name":"hijk", "nickname":"hijk","password":"123456","gender":"male","dob":"1989-02-28","email":"hijk@gmail.com","device_id":"sffdg5645445","os":"ios","social_id":"sdjaljdlasldklsdsdls"] as Dictionary<String, String>


        do{
            request.httpBody =  try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: params, options: JSONSerialization.WritingOptions.prettyPrinted)
        }
        catch
        {

        }
        request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
        request.addValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Accept")
        let  task = session.dataTask(with: request, completionHandler: {(data,response,error) in


            if (data != nil)
            {
                do{
                    let dict =  try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.mutableLeaves)
                    print(dict);
                }
                catch
                {

                }

            }

        }
        )

        task.resume()
    }
```